# Backbone.js Firefox issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

Hello I am using Backbone.js + require.js for my application I have a problem rendering template in Firefox. it works fine in Chrome and Ie

here is the code to render

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/home/main.html'
], function ($, _, Backbone, mainHomeTemplate) {

    var mainHomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#page"),
        render: function () {
//            console.log("loading template");
            this.el.html(mainHomeTemplate);
        }
    });
    return new mainHomeView;
});
```

can some one let me know whats the issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: is the code wrapped in $(document).ready({...}) ?

Comment: where do you want me to wrap? in the view?

Comment: In other words, are you sure $("#page") is accessible at the time of code executing? I suggest you to wrap your whole code in .ready() and check then.

Answer (score 0):

`this.el` is a reference to the raw DOM element of the view.  I guess Chrome must have an HTML method on its raw DOM elements, but (evidently) Firefox doesn't.

In any case, what you really want is the jQuery-wrapped version of that same element, which you can get using `this.$el`.  If for some reason you're using an older version of Backbone ($el was added somewhat recently) you can instead just do `$(this.el)`; it will work the same, but it's slightly less convenient.

If you use that jQuery-wrapped version of the element, then your `.html(mainHomeTemplate)` call will work, because jQuery objects always have a "html" method.

Comment: I tried that but looks like i still have the same issue i dont see any javascript errors in my firebug console. Is there something i am missing?

Comment: I'd imagine your el isn't what you think it is.  You can try console.logging it to confirm as much.  If I'm correct, you might want to try setting the el (via .setElement) in your view's initialize method (or even in render itself, depending on the timing of how you're invoking things).